# FtpWebRequest alternative for .net core

Tags: c#, ftp, .net-core

Looks like .Net Core team has no plans to implement FtpWebRequest or some alternative, as mentioned in this [issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7439). Also I looked on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) and not find any third party FTP-support libraries for net core.

I need to download XML with some settings via FTP in my program. Do I have any other way to do it?

Comment: FYI, [`FtpWebRequest` is planned to be included in .Net Standard 2.0 / .Net Core vNext](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Net.FtpWebRequest). Though that doesn't help you right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found solution. [CoreFtp](https://github.com/sparkeh9/CoreFTP)

Comment: [FluentFTP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentFTP/) is an option now too.